Issue with flexbox assignment
We are doing an assignment on flexboxes, and I don't know why it won't put spaces between the sections in my main. I had spaces between them at some point, then messed around a bit and now they just wont split. I am so confused. I've been messing with margin and padding and the whole justify-content thing but it wont work. I just want them to be three seperated boxes.


header,
footer {
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  background-color: lightpink;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10%;
  padding: 20px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Factoids Homework</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header id="header-main">
    <h1>Factoids</h1>
  </header>
  
  <main>
    <section class="content-section" id="div-one">
      <h2>Im Thinking of Ending Things</h2>

      <p>A popular psychological horror book by Iain Reid. Set during a snowy road trip, a girl is going to meet her boyfriends parents but is really considering leaving and ending things with him. It would be hard to really be able to describe the plot
        in more depth than that as this book is better when going in as blind as possible. A read that blends horror, psychological, and weirdness and will make you uncomfortable, but you wont know exactly why youre uncomfortable.</p>

      <a href="https://electricliterature.com/im-thinking-of-ending-things-as-lit-fic-philosophical-tract-and-thriller/">More</a>
    </section>

<section class="content-section" id="div-two">
      <h2>Gemini Home Entertainment</h2>

      <p>There is a niche genre of online horror that they call analog horror. It is basically the ability to use social media, or online platforms to build a horror story. The youtube series Gemini Home Entertainment is very popular among the people who
        watch analog horror. It is a series in the style of vhs tapes that is building a story of a world where these body snatcher type creatures exist. The most interesting part of this though is that the series is made by only one or two people. Which
        just makes it impressive. </p>

      <a href="https://www.youtube.com/GEMINIHOMEENTERTAINMENT">More</a>
    </section>
    
    <section class="content-section" id="div-three">
      <h2>Crows</h2>

      <p>
        Crows are one of the smartest species of bird to exist in the United States. Often found in open patches of land by woods, and love to congregate in fields as it is easy to spot things around them. They make and use the tools they make to help when finding
        food or disturding other tree climbers that could possibly take their food. It is also very well known that if you were to bother a crow they can remember your face, and hold a grudge. So its best to leave your local crows alone.
      </p>
      <a href="https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/American_Crow/overview">More</a>
    </section>
  </main>

  <footer id="footer-main">
    <p>KMO &copy 2024</p>
  </footer>
</body>
</html>




Please provide a screenshot of what the expected output is

It depends on what sort of spacing you want but this link shows a basic way of adding a gap between items: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

You can add a gap attribute. This will give you the look you want. The following code shows how to add it.
main {
  background-color: lightpink;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 10%;
  padding: 20px;
  gap:50px;
} 

